# Jenkins Editable Email Notification plugin is not sending emails to multiple recipients

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

Email Notification plugin version : 2.57
Jenkins version: 2.50

When I specify multiple recipients for emails I don't get any email. But when I specify only one recipient I get emails. Why so ?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: How are you specifying multiple emails ? comma separated ? space separated ?Tip : you can test sending multiple emails from manage jenkins / configure /Test configuration by sending test e-mail.

Comment: @prudviraj I tried semicolon separated, space separated, space separated but still seeing an error.

Comment: Did you try testing  sending multiple emails from manage jenkins / configure /Test configuration by sending test e-mail ? and you can enable debug mode from global page.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this issue? I am encountering the same thing...

Comment: @RedRoses I don't remember what I did. Sorry.